# Typo3 javascript loading issue

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I work with Typo3 ver.12.4. In the extension template file I use this line to load javascript

`<v:asset.script name="video_js" path="EXT:cs2_video/Resources/Public/JavaScript/video.js" async="1" standalone="1" overwrite="1" fluid="1"/>`

When page is rendered, the page source code look like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ems.stage.cs.com/https://ems.stage.cs.com/typo3temp/assets/vhs-assets-video_js.js" async="async"></script>`

where the 'http://domain/' is doubled.

Console says

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ems.stage.cs.com/https://ems.stage.cs.com/typo3temp/assets/vhs-assets-news_slider_js.js”`

Funny is that the dev server works just fine, only stage server does not.

Most probably it is some configuration issue on the stage server, I tried to identify the difference between two servers, no succes.

Does anyone had that experience?

Comment: Did you check the site configuration? On Stage there could be the full domain incl. scheme while on Dev it's only a `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move from vhs to fluid and use f:asset.script:

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Asset/Script.html